# Как добавить telegram бота в канал если они созданы одним и тем же аккаунтом?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Заметил такую хитрость у Telegram. Он не позволяет добавить бота в кпнал если они оба (и бот и канал) мозданы одним и тем же аккаунтом. Т.е. имеют одного и того же владельца. Это как-то можно обойти?

Comment: Защита от накрутки наверное...

Comment: ничего подобного, такого ограничения нет

Comment: @Anatol тогда непонятно в чем же дело с моим ботом

Comment: Я тоже подобное наблюдал.
При добавлении пользователя на канал (и в группу так же), при поиске бот не обнаруживался. Но попробовал создать еще бота. Плюс добавил боту и "фотку" и описание.
В итоге при поиске бот нашелся и был добавлен. Вероятно, это проблема Телеграма. То он находит бота, то не находит.
Попробуйте создать еще одного? Или подождать немного?

Comment: Мой бот содержит и фотку и описание... Все равно не находится. А вот вновь созданные боты вполне находятся и добавляются в каналы. Мистика какая-то

Comment: На десктопной версии получается добавить бота в канал.